# How can I add an additional condition to this query (using CASE)?

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, case

Here's my query so far:

> SELECT
>           posts.title
>           , SUM(CASE comments.status WHEN 'approved' THEN 1 END) AS commentsCount
>           FROM posts
>           INNER JOIN comments
>               ON comments.postID = posts.id
>           WHERE
>               posts.status = ?
>           GROUP BY
>               posts.title
>           ORDER BY
>               commentsCount DESC
>           LIMIT 5

I need to have it also check that `comment.flagged` = 0 when it gets `commentsCount`. I tried adding additional `CASE`s within the `SUM()` call, but this resulted in a fatal error. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you're really trying to do is this:

```
SELECT
posts.title
, COUNT(*) AS commentsCount
FROM posts
INNER JOIN comments
ON comments.postID = posts.id
AND comments.status = 'approved'
AND comments.flagged = 0
WHERE
posts.status = ?
GROUP BY
posts.title
ORDER BY
commentsCount DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Since you're only interested in `comments` whose `status` is `'approved'`, the condition should be in join condition.

Edit: I have updated the query assuming you want to count comments whose `status` is `'approved'` and `flagged` is equal to `0`.

Comment: I need to fetch comments that are approved and their flagged column = 0. I tried your SQL, and got this error message: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN 'approved' WHERE posts.status = ? GROUP BY posts.title ORDER'

Comment: Could you explain what you are actually trying to achieve in your question, please? In plain English. For example "I am trying to get the 5 posts with the most comments whose status is 'approved'" except with the flagged part.

Comment: Except for the COUNT(*), this code works fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
posts.title
, SUM(IF ((comments.status='approved' AND  comments.flagged = 0),1,0)) AS commentsCount
FROM posts
INNER JOIN comments
ON comments.postID = posts.id
WHERE
posts.status = ?
GROUP BY
posts.title
ORDER BY
commentsCount DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This code gives me this error:
'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),1,0) AS commentsCount FROM posts INNER JOIN comments ON comments.postID = p'

Comment: This works now, thanks :)
I am curious as to if your method is more or less efficient than my own answer that I posted.

Comment: @Arms, preface each SELECT with EXPLAIN to see the query strategy that the db intends to use. Then you'll have a good idea of which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of Josh Davis' SQL, here's what worked for me:

> SELECT
>           posts.title
>           , posts.slug
>           , COUNT(comments.id) AS commentsCount
>           FROM posts
>           INNER JOIN comments
>           ON comments.postID = posts.id
>           AND comments.status = 'approved'
>           AND comments.flagged = 0
>           WHERE
>           posts.status = ?
>           GROUP BY
>           posts.title
>           ORDER BY
>           commentsCount DESC
>           LIMIT 5